# How can I convert GPathResult to text without pretty format

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I'm trying to use groovy to update Jenkins job config.xml by the following code

```
def updateParameter(String key, String value){

    println "changing defult value as $value for key $key"

    def xml = new XmlSlurper().parseText(jobConfig)
    xml.properties.'hudson.model.ParametersDefinitionProperty'.'parameterDefinitions'.'hudson.model.StringParameterDefinition'.each {
        println 'found parameter: ' + it.name
        if(it.name.text() == key){
            println('default value changed')
            it.defaultValue=value
        }
    }
    jobConfig = XmlUtil.serialize(xml)
}
```

When running jobConfig = XmlUtil.serialize(xml), it changes the format, which is pretty, but I lost link break in pipeline plugin, so pipeline script doesn't work anymore. Is there a way to convert GPathResult to String without format changing?

Best Regards,

Eric

Comment: Please see if examples here helps http://mrhaki.blogspot.in/2012/10/groovy-goodness-pretty-print-xml.html

Comment: @Rao thx for the comments

Answer (score 0):

It is all my fault, the line breaks were removed when I read the xml. It seems XmlUtil.serialize(xml) doen't format the text of a xml tag, which is good :)

Best Regards,

Eric